# Implementing Naive Bayes Nearest Neighbor (NBNN) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, knn

I posted this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126867/naive-bayes-nearest-neighbor-nbnn-implementation-problems-in-matlab) on the CV SO a few days ago but it has gone basically unobserved by the forum. I'm trying to implement [NBNN](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~irani/PAPERS/InDefenceOfNN_CVPR08.pdf) in MATLAB to do image classification on the CIFAR-10 image dataset. The algorithm is pretty simple, and I'm confident in it's correctness, however, I'm receiving terrible accuracy rates with 22-28%. I'm unsure why and I'm hoping someone who has experience with image classification or the algorithm could point me in the right direction. The algorithm learns off of SIFT image descriptors, which could be one of the reasons why it's under-performing. Matlab only has a SURF feature detector. From what I've read, SURF/SIFT are basically equivalent. I've been using `features`, (nDescriptros x 64) obtained from the function below to train my model.

```
points = detectSURFFeatures(rgb2gray(image));
[features,valid_points] = extractFeatures(image,points);
```

Another possible issue with the CIFAR dataset and this approach is the small size of the images. Each image is 32 x 32 images which, I beleive, makes feature detection very difficult. I've played around with the different octave settings in the `detectSURFFeatures()` but nothing has brought my accuracy above 28%.

The annotated code for the approach is below. It's difficult to understand but still might be helpful.

Hopefully someone can help me out.

```
for i = 3001:4000 %Train on the first 3000 instances and test on the remaining 1000.
    closeness = [];
    for j = 1:10 %loop over the 10 catergories
        class = train(trainLabel==j,:); % Pull out all descriptors that belong to class j
        descriptor = test(test_id==i,:); % Pull out all descriptors for image i
        [idx,dist] = knnsearch(class,descriptor,'K',1); % Find the distance between the descriptors and the closest labeled descriptor in class j.
        total = sum(dist); % sum up distances
        closeness = [closeness,sum(total)]; % append a vector of the image-to-class distances.
    end
    [val,cat] = min(closeness); % Find choose the class that resulted in the lowest, summed distance.
    predLabel = [predLabel;cat]; % Append to a vector of labels.
    i
end
```

Comment: You detect the SURF features using a grayscale image, but extract features from the original RGB image. Does this work as you expect? How are results if you use `extractFeatures` on the grayscale image?

Comment: So detecting features has been has been an area of uncertainty for me. I tried detecting surf features on the 32x32 images but received a very sparse output. Only a one or two features would be detected, in some cases no features were detected. After playing with resizing, I realized that I received more features the larger the image was, so I ended up resizing the the image to a 256x256 before running feature detection on it. Here are the two lines I use to extract features. `points = detectSURFFeatures(I);` then `[features,valid_points] = extractFeatures(I,points)`.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are 32x32 pixels, then trying to detect interest points is not a good idea.  As you have observed, you would get very few features, if any.  Upsampling the images is one option. Another option is to use a global descriptor like HOG (`extractHOGFeatures`).

Comment: Dima, it seems you're into Image Processing - could you assist us open this dedicated group: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66531/computer-vision/72084 Just vote to questions with less than 10 up votes. Thanks.